# Applying Multiple Filters on List

Tags: scala

Given these two functions:

```
scala> def maybe(x: Int): Boolean = x % 2 == 0
maybe: (x: Int)Boolean

scala> def good(x: Int): Boolean = x == 10
good: (x: Int)Boolean
```

Can I apply both `good` and `maybe` functions together?

```
scala> List(10) filter good filter maybe
res104: List[Int] = List(10)

scala> List(10) filter (good && maybe)
<console>:17: error: missing arguments for method good;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              List(10) filter (good && maybe)
                               ^
```

Comment: Tried partial functions with no success, e.g `val maybe = (x: Int) => x %2 == 0`  and  `val good = (x: Int) => x == 10` ; then on calling `List(10) filter (good && maybe)` it shows `error: value && is not a member of Int => Boolean`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could evaluate them inside an anonymous function:

```
List(10) filter { x => good(x) && maybe(x) }
```

You can't really use `andThen` because composition is like the transitive property.

```
[(A => Boolean) && (A => Boolean)] != [(A => B) => C]
// ^ What you want                     ^ Composition
```

Comment: Thanks, hsun. Also, the benefit of using your approach is that it's only necessary to traverse the `List` once. Using two `filter`'s (as I had) will result in two traversals of the `List`.

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> def maybe(x: Int): Boolean = x % 2 == 0
maybe: (x: Int)Boolean

scala> def good(x: Int): Boolean = x % 3 == 0
good: (x: Int)Boolean

scala> (1 to 20) filter { i => List(good _, maybe _).forall(_(i)) }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(6, 12, 18)
```

Comment: This will try to create the list on every iteration and doesn't look idomatic.

Comment: @hsun324 If you have a bunch of predicates, forall is pretty idiomatic. Not so much for two.

Comment: I up-voted your answer, @som-snytt, and learned about the usage of partial function application with `filter`. However, I find hsun's answer here to be simpler.

Comment: I think you're both right. But it's nice to have options.